# Cannot install kdenlive on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kdenlive

I've tried to install `kdenlive` from the terminal by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kdenlive : Depends: kdenlive-data (= 0.9.2-0ubuntu0~sunab~precise2) but 0.9.3+git20120701.53f9c1b9-0ubuntu0~sunab~oneiric1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help, please?

(It worked perfectly before I updated to the new Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you on oneiric or precise ?

Comment: It is problem with packaging. File a bug or message the owner of the ppa.

Comment: @Postadelmaga Have no idea. How do I find out? Sorry for the ignorance. :D

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Have no idea how to do any of those. Please help me out with details...

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be that you are on Ubuntu 12.04 and added the personal package archive for Ubuntu 11.10. Or the PPA doesn't work properly.

The best thing to do, in my opinion, is to remove the repository. Kdenlive installs fine without it.
In terminal you can do it with the following command:
`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release`
Then you can proceed with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive`

Comment: I'm not very good with technology.

Comment: I'm not very good with technology (new to Ubuntu). Can you please tell me how to proceed? Many thanks

Comment: @Raluca OK. Added some instructions

Comment: BlaXpirit, here's the outcome (doesn't seem too positive):

Comment: @ BlaXpiritError: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu precise main' doesn't exist in a sourcelist file
Error: 'deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu precise main' doesn't exist in a sourcelist file

Comment: and the second command's outcome:The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kdenlive : Depends: libmlt4 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: kdenlive-data (= 0.8.2.1-1ubuntu1) but 0.9.3+git20120701.53f9c1b9-0ubuntu0~sunab~oneiric1 is to be installed
            Recommends: swh-plugins but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: recordmydesktop but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @Raluca So you have some broken packages. That's never pleasant... Try the command `sudo apt-get install -f` and if that doesn't work you could [search](http://google.com/search?q=ubuntu+apt-get+fix+broken+packages) for a solution. I found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) but I've never tried it.

Comment: This always happens whenever I upgrade (I think I'll never upgrade again!) Result: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-26
  linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.  Do I remove them?(Sorry for this...terminal psychobabble totally out-dates me, as in fact the whole system) Many thanks for the help

Comment: @Raluca Oh yes, I've never had a successful dist-upgrade. I have a separate `/` and `/home` partitions so I just reinstall every time a new version comes out. No, don't remove these packages. I guess you could try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` (of course if you're using Ubuntu itself; for other flavors that would be `kubuntu-desktop` etc.). Also, this particular 'question' of yours seems to require a lot of communication, so maybe a [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/) would be better.